# Can I get three months data in chatbase session flow report?Is it possible?

Tags: chatbase

I am using Chatbase Generic Message API in my webhook and want to see three months to one year data in my chatbase session flow report.Is it possible to see that data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose any arbitrary date range as far back as July 2018 using the [Custom Date Range Selector](https://chatbase.com/documentation/report-filters#custdaterange).

Please note that if you are uploading historical message data, only messages with a timestamp within 48 hours of the time of upload will be processed in the Session Flow report. Processing times and report availability will adhere to this [chart](https://chatbase.com/documentation/faq#Reports) in our FAQ.